# error using shared TCPConnector in aiohttp

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I've been trying to use a connection pool in aiohttp without much luck. The use case is the code makes requests to a few servers repeatedly and I don't want to recreate the connections on every request. Here is some code to reproduce the problem (The error is `Timeout context manager should be used inside a task`):

```
import asyncio
import logging
from asyncio import Future
from typing import Dict, List

from aiohttp import ClientTimeout, ClientSession, TCPConnector


class UrlService:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connector: TCPConnector = TCPConnector()

    async def _fetch(self, session:ClientSession, url:str):
        logging.info('requesting data from %s', url)
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            data = await response.text()
            logging.info('received data from %s', url)
            if response.status != 200:
                text = await response.text()
                return f'non 200 status for {url}: {text.strip()}'

            return data

    async def _make_requests(self, urls: List[str]) -> Future:

        async with ClientSession(timeout=ClientTimeout(10),
                                 connector=self.connector,
                                 connector_owner=False) as session:
            coroutines = []
            for url in urls:
                coroutines.append(self._fetch(session, url))

            return await asyncio.gather(*coroutines)

    def download(self, urls: List[str]) -> Dict[str, Dict]:
        responses = asyncio.run(self._make_requests(urls))
        return dict(zip(urls, responses))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url_service = UrlService()
    search_urls = ['https://google.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://bing.com']
    data = url_service.download(search_urls)

    for url, resp in data.items():
        print(f'****** {url} ******')
        print(f'  resp len: {len(resp)}')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this issue](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiobotocore/issues/440#issuecomment-373820081) from `aiobotocore`, I think the issue is that you are creating the `TCPConnector()` outside of any pre-existing event loop context. Internally, `TCPConnector` will get it's own event loop when it's constructed, and end up associated to that. Then, when you do `asyncio.run()`, you end up with another event loop instance that's actually used to run `_make_requests`, which then tries to use the `TCPConnector` associated to a different event loop. This mismatch seems to be the cause of the error.

When I move `self.connector = TCPConnector()` line into the body of `_make_requests()`, the issue goes away.

Comment: yep, i noticed the warning also goes away. the problem is i want to use this code in a quart server route, so i need to reuse the pool across API requests (and across _make_requests() call). however, if I initialize the connector only once in one of the asyncs call i get an "Event loop is closed" RuntimeError.

Comment: I think because `asyncio.run()` is creating a new loop on each call, and then closing it when it's done, you're not going to be able to share the connector across calls that are wrapped by it. However, If you are intending to use this from quart, there should be no need to use `asyncio.run()`, since quart handlers are already running on an event loop, right?

Comment: yes, you're right! i got the appropriate event loop in a `before_first_request` handler and it's working perfectly.